# Syntax error in create table statement - Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ddl

```
Create table Customers 
(
customerid              number(10) PRIMARY KEY; 
First_name              varchar2(100); 
last_name               varchar2(100); 
house_number            number(10); 
street                  number(10);  
postcode                number(5); 
home_phone_number       number(10);  
mobile_phone_number     number(10);  
email_address           varchar2(100); 
DOB                     date
);
```

Comment: what's the error ? which DBMS ? we can not guess what's in your mind

Comment: Sorry, Im using access 2010 and the error is "syntax error in create table statement. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your DDL statement, with the field type substitutions @Mureinik suggested, works in Access 2010, but only if you execute it from ADO:

```sql
Create table Customers (
    customerid              numeric(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    First_name              varchar(100),
    last_name               varchar(100), 
    house_number            numeric(10),
    street                  numeric(10),  
    postcode                numeric(5),
    home_phone_number       numeric(10),
    mobile_phone_number     numeric(10),  
    email_address           varchar(100),
    DOB                     datetime
    );
```

I loaded the statement into a string variable, *strCreate*, and executed it like this ...

```vb
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strCreate
```

`CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object.

That statement will throw a syntax error when executed via DAO ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute strCreate  ' <-- "Syntax error"
```

If you're executing the statement from the Access query designer, that also uses DAO and the statement will fail.

Although the statement executed successfully from ADO, I'm unsure the resulting data types for those `Numeric()` fields are what you actually want.  I'm not accustomed to seeing `Decimal` field type used for a primary key.  More often, people choose `AutoNumber`, which is based on `Long Integer`. (But I'm not saying `Decimal` is a bad choice if that's what you really want.)

[image: Customers table in Table Design view]

Answer (score 1):

After each column definition you should have a comma (`,`), not a semicolon (`;`).
Additionally, this script looks as though it was borrowed from Oracle. In access, the corresponding types for `varchar2`, `number` and `date` are `varchar`, `numeric` and `datetime`, respectively:

```
Create table Customers 
(
customerid              numeric(10) PRIMARY KEY,
First_name              varchar(100),
last_name               varchar(100), 
house_number            numeric(10),
street                  numeric(10),  
postcode                numeric(5),
home_phone_number       numeric(10),
mobile_phone_number     numeric(10),  
email_address           varchar(100),
DOB                     datetime
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but its still coming up with the same error :/

Comment: @Harry just noticed your types were off, please see the edited answer

Comment: Not sure for access it might only have datetime

Comment: @Mihai you are correct, I missed that one. Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: hmm thanks for your help but its strange that it's still coming up with the same error! :(